# How to resolve "ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels" error while processing time series data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, valueerror

```
                       cube   timestamp          temp   
timestamp               
2022-08-01 00:15:05.135  A1       2022-08-01 00:15:05.135    NaN

2022-08-01 00:15:37.255  A1       2022-08-01 00:15:37.255    23.17  

2022-08-01 00:23:05.139  A1       2022-08-01 00:23:05.139    NaN    

2022-08-01 00:23:15.137  A1       2022-08-01 00:23:15.137    NaN    

2022-08-11 11:33:20.738  P19      2022-08-11 00:15:05.135    NaN
```

I am trying to interpolate NaN value in temperature based on the timestamp with respect to the cubes by using the below code

```
idata.set_index(idata['timestamp'],inplace = True)

idata['temp'] = idata.groupby('cube')['temp'].apply(lambda x:x.interpolate(method="time",limit_direction = "both"))
```

while executing this code, I am getting the error "ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels". I cannot remove the duplicate labels(timestamp) as it may belong to
different cubes. please suggest the alternative to handle this situation.

Comment: The dataframe's `reset_index` method will move the index to a regular columns and use integers for th index. After that, you should be able to interpolate as expected. You can set the columns back to the original value with `set_index('timestamp')`.

Answer (score 0):

You might have duplicated values in the column you want to use as index. Index values need to be unique.

You can find them with `df['timestamp'].duplicated()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this situation, I cant remove the duplicated timestamp as it may belong to the different cube. Is there any other way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem stems from setting a duplicated index first, then doing `groupby`. Instead, I suggest you group by `cube` first, then do the interpolation inside each group:

```py
def interp_group(g):
     g.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
     g['temp'] = g.temp.interpolate(method="time",limit_direction = "both")
     return g

cubes = df.groupby('cube')
interpolated = groups.apply(f)
```

You get back a dataframe with a `MultiIndex`, with the group as first level and the timestamp as second. The column `temp` is interpolated as you wanted:

```py
In [36]: interpolated
Out[36]:
                              cube   temp
cube timestamp
  A1 2022-08-01 00:15:05.135    A1  23.17
     2022-08-01 00:15:37.255    A1  23.17
     2022-08-01 00:23:05.139    A1  23.17
     2022-08-01 00:23:15.137    A1  23.17
 P19 2022-08-11 00:15:05.135   P19    NaN
```

Or, if you prefer a less readable one-liner:

```py
df.groupby('cube').apply(lambda g: g.set_index('timestamp').temp.interpolate(method="time",limit_direction = "both"))
```